# Don't render component until image has loaded?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have some React components which contain images, their height changes based on the image loading (i.e. ).

The components are all added to a grid, however I don't want them to be added to the grid until after the image has loaded.

I tried doing something like this:

```
class CardInstance {
    Card: JSX.Element;
    Id: number;
    loaded: boolean = false;
};

cards: CardInstance[] = [];

getCard(src: CardData): CardInstance
{
    for (var i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i++)
    {
        var subCard = this.cards[i].Card;
        if (this.cards[i].Id == src.id)
            return this.cards[i];
    }

    var card = new CardInstance();
    card.Id = src.id;
    card.Card = <div key={src.id}><Card imageLoaded={this.imageLoaded} width={this.props.columnwidth} src={src} /></div>;
    this.cards.push(card);

    return card;
}

imageLoaded(cardId: number)
{
// get card instance using card id..
cardInstance.Loaded = true;
}
```

In the render function I basically call 'getCard' for each CardData in my props (not shown in above code), from the returned CardInstance I check the boolean 'loaded', if true I add it to an array to render.

^ The above doesn't work obviously because the element is not mounted, therefore doesn't render or attempt to load the image and the imageLoaded callback (which is hooked up to an img element via onLoaded inside the card) doesn't get created or loaded.

Is this possible to do using my method or another?

Comment: Have you got any code to demonstrate this component? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MichaelHancock I didn't want to show my only idea to accomplish this because it's so silly, nevertheless I updated my question.

Comment: No matter how silly it is, it will give everyone trying to answer your question somewhere to start. Thanks for updating it